# How can I exceed Active Collab API retrieve records?

Tags: activecollab

I am using Active Collab API for fetching all discussions related to one project , but in json response I am getting only 25 discussions but there are around 78 discussions exists. So anyone can help me here for retrieving all discussions related to corresponding project?

Comment: Question about retrieval of paginated results has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40020858/338473

Comment: @llija, I review the link, but there is not any contents that can resolve my query

Comment: There's no way to get all the records with one request when data set is paginated. You need to loop through pages (and that IS the answer to your question). Check the *Alternative* bit of the answer for the easiest approach.