# ActiveCollab API return all active projects

Tags: api, project, activecollab

We have problem with API from ActiveCollab. We are using this API point:

https://app.activecollab.com/117236/api/v1/projects/

but it is not returning all active projects. For example there is not included project "CrossMasters: Marketing" (https://app.activecollab.com/117236/projects/7).

Can you help us with that? Just a few days ago, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Projects API is paginated, and it returns 50 projects with latest activity. You can access other pages by adding `page` GET attribute. For example, you can request second page of projects by calling:

https://app.activecollab.com/117236/api/v1/projects?page=2

You can check pagination headers to see how many projects are there actually, and implement a loop based on that information, or simply go page by page until you get to a page that returns no results. More info about this can be found in this StackOverflow answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40020858/338473